# row select event on Datatable with partial submit dont work primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have prime faces form that have set of input elements and finally button let's call it i_BTN which is not the submit button and datatable let's call it f_DT.

My logic is to fill set of elements let's is call these elements : 
inpt_1 and inpt_2 not all elements and when click on i_BTN it is  add new record in f_DT.

I am using partial submit in i_BTN to to that logic cause i don't to submit all fields.
Button do its task fine and new record is added in f_DT
My big deal is :
when i am add ajax in f_DT to catch rowSelect the SelectEvent object pass with null value.
with full submit SelectEvent is passed with value.

```
<h:form id="generalForm">
<p:inputText label="full_submit_input_one" id="inpt1"/>
<p:inputText label="full_submit_input_two" id="inpt2"/>

<h:panelGrid columns="4" id="partial_submit_Panel">
    <p:inputText label="partial_submit_input_one" id="inpt3"/>
    <p:inputText label="partial_submit_input_two" id="inpt4"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:dataTable id="itemDT" var="item"  value="#{itemView.items}" selectionMode="multiple"
        selection="#{itemView.selectedItems}" 
        rowKey="#{fee.Id}">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            listener="#{dtFeesView.onRowSelect}" />
    <p:column headerText="Input three">
        <h:outputText value="#{fee.inpt3}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Input four">
        <h:outputText value="#{fee.inpt4}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton value="Full Submit"  actionListener="#{itemView.add}"/>
<p:commandButton value="Partial Submit"  actionListener="#{itemView.insertRecord}" process=":generalForm:partial_submit_Panel"/>
```

```
@ManagedBean(name="itemView")
@ViewScoped
public class ItemView{
    private ItemModel selectedItems[];
    // getters and setters for selectedItems
    private List<ItemModel> items;
    // getters and setters for items

    public void add(){
        // add item to i.e database
    }

    public void insertRecord(){
        // add itemModels  to items list 
    }
    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        ItemModel model =(ItemModel)event.getObject();
        // model is null in case of process with value :generalForm:partial_submit_Panel
        //model is not null in case of process with value generalForm "submit full form"
    }
}
```

please help.
regards.

Comment: Some examples are required, please - [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks Tiny for hit .I added sample code.